# Get DataList control ID using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to set a dropdownlist value to the same as another but I cannot find the controls because they are embedded in a DataList.

This is what I am trying:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function () {
  var ddl1 = $('#<%= dataListID.ClientID%>').Find('[id$=ddl1]'),
      ddl2 = $('#<%= dataListID.ClientID%>').Find('[id$=ddl2]')

  $(ddl1).change(function () {
    var Selected = $(this).val();
    $(ddl2).val(Selected);
  });
});
```

**QUESTION**

How to find the ID of a DataList control using javascript?

**NOTE**

- *I get no errors, but I also get no results.*
- *I believe the issue is that the control ID will be unique on each data row.*
- *In this instance I only have one row in my datalist.*

Comment: Have you tried `$(/*selector*/).attr('id');`?

Comment: @MjrKusanagi could you expand on this?

Comment: `var Selected = $(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Thanks for your help but my issue is finding the ddl ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. **ID's** cause so much pain. So I just used **CssClass**.

```
$(function () {
  $('.ddl1').change(function () {
    var Selected = $(this).val();
    $('.ddl2').val(Selected);
  });
});
```

**Note:** *if you have several rows i.e several repeated classes they will all change.*